# GCC precompiler macro ## , concatenate with token that is another macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

As you can see concatenating a token works,
also a token being another macro works,
but when a token is a macro it doesn't seem to work?

```
longNameForaFunction_one(){return 1;}
longNameForaFunction_two(){return 2;}
longNameForaFunction_third(){return 3;}
two(){return 2;}
#define bar two
#define foo(x)(longNameForaFunction_##x())
#define three third
main(){
printf("%d\n",foo(one)); // 1

printf("%d\n",foo(two)); // 2

printf("%d\n",bar()); // 2

// printf("%d\n",foo(three)); // this doesn't work  
}
```

The last row gives this error if uncommented;

> undefined reference to `longNameForaFunction_three'

```
#define three third
```

Seems to have no effect

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##fc/BCoMwDAbgu09RlLEWNkR39O5xTzAYXVu1bCajVhSGz@7iED3MrYdCyZfkrzqWSo3jA6E8y9rk6GTegvIW4YpguHg541sHLMmGYFP5DleV/lSVdXp1J3JfjZE2hQXDbtIxKi7vApH3gm/OjaKeC7FQXzkz3bQsGGtpgTYET2fBFzzc6QuEh2ka/UyIjMUxSwJGZ4NQgJmkW4Qy8n/1z4gpzIwoUsM0mgb2nnXo7tQxjG8)

Comment: Use more white space.  Use `#define EVALUATOR(x) x` and `#define CONCATENATE(x, y) x ## y` and then `#define foo(x) CONCATENATE(longNameForaFunction_, EVALUATOR(x))`.  And this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's why you need to provide another level before it works - the macro parameter will be expanded before it is passed to `foo`.

```
#define foo(x)(longNameForaFunction_##x())
#define foo1(x) foo(x)
#define three third

..

printf("%d\n",foo1(three));
```